# ExpoModulesCore/EXAppDelegatesLoader.h' file not found while archiving my project from xcode

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, expo

I have encountered some issues while **archiving** my react native project from xcode.

The project started as an expo project and then I ejected from Expo. Its also worth mentioning that the project actually works and build correctly but the only problem happens when I'm archiving it to publish it to the store!

I checked resources out there and nothing solved the issues.

### Error

[image]

The error.

The three errors texts:

1. `ExpoModulesCore/EXAppDelegatesLoader.h' file not found`
2. `React/CoreModulesPlugins.h' file not found`
3. `could not build Objective-C module 'ExpoModulesCore'`

They are all related to expo core modules it seems.

Here is my `package.json file

```
{
  "name": "Bewitch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~5.0.0",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "~5.0.0",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "0.10.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/configure-splash-screen": "^0.6.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "github:react-native-async-storage/async-storage",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.15",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "async-storage": "^0.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.11",
    "expo": "~48.0.9",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "^1.1.2",
    "expo-modules-core": "^1.2.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^9.6.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-mlkit-ocr": "^0.2.5",
    "react-native-purchases": "^5.13.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-share-menu": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and here is my Podfile:

````
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}
pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods',
  :deterministic_uuids => false

prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...), which will be excluded. To fix this,
# you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` in `react-native.config.js`
#
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
#   }
# }
# ```
flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
if ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == '1' then
  # Explicitly disabled through environment variables
  flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
elsif podfile_properties.key?('ios.flipper') then
  # Configure Flipper in Podfile.properties.json
  if podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] == 'true' then
    flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug", "Release"])
  elsif podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] != 'false' then
    flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug", "Release"], { 'Flipper' => podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] })
  end
end

target 'datingassistant' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']
  use_frameworks! :linkage => ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS'].to_sym if ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work if enabled
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config
  )

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == "React-Core-AccessibilityResources"
          target.remove_from_project
        end
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

    # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
    # when building for devices.
    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
      .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
      target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
        resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end
````

Appreciate your help as this is the only stopper from publishing my app.